# Linear forms on the abelian group of integer sequences

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series

Let $S = \mathbf{Z}^\mathbf{N}$ be the abelian group of integer valued sequences. For each $i \in \mathbf{N}$ note $\delta_i\in S$ the sequence $(0,0,...,0,1,0,...)$ with the one at the $ith$ place.

I would like to show that any $\mathbf{Z}$-linear function $S \to \mathbf{Z}$  has to be zero on all but finitely many $\delta_i$.

Actually I know (I think) how to prove the result by the following indirect argument : note $T := \mathbf{Z}^{(\mathbf{N})}$ for the free abelian group of compactly supported sequences (i.e. only a finite number of entry are non-zero). Basically what we want to show is that $S^* = T$ where $S^*= Hom_\mathbf{Z}(S,\mathbf{Z})$ is the $\mathbf{Z}$-linear dual of $S$. The following paper : https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1103033984 proves that $T$ is reflexive i.e. $T^{**} = T$ (just use the fact that $\mathbf{Z}_{(p)}$ is not complete).  But it is also easy to prove that $T^* = S$ which implies that $S^* = T$ so we are done.

**So i'm really looking for a direct argument.** If possible one which follows the intuition that if you have a linear form which is non zero (positive say) on all the $\delta_i$ for $i$ in an infinite subset $I \subset \mathbf{N}$ then $f(\sum_{i \in I} \delta_i)$ would have to be infinite.

Comment: Oh well the answer is here : http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10239/is-it-true-that-as-bbb-z-modules-the-polynomial-ring-and-the-power-series-r